# SQL Server in Docker CREATE INDEX failed because the following SET options have incorrect settings: ‘QUOTED_IDENTIFIER’

Tags: sql-server, docker, dockerfile, sql-server-linux

I have a SQL Server Dockerfile with my import-data.sh importing `*.sql` files from a sql-data folder. Everything works if I run the `*.sql` files from a tool like Datagrip but the import fails with this error message when it's ran automatically.

Error message:

> Msg 1934, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
>   CREATE INDEX failed because the following SET options have incorrect settings: 'QUOTED_IDENTIFIER'. Verify that SET options are correct for use with indexed views and/or indexes on computed columns and/or filtered indexes and/or query notifications and/or XML data type methods and/or spatial index operations.

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM microsoft/mssql-server-linux:2017-latest

RUN mkdir /sql-data/
EXPOSE 1433

COPY entrypoint.sh /usr/local/bin/
RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/entrypoint.sh

COPY import-data.sh /usr/src/app/
RUN chmod +x /usr/src/app/import-data.sh

# Copy SQL Scripts to sql-data for processing
COPY ./sql-data/*.sql /sql-data/

CMD /bin/bash /usr/local/bin/entrypoint.sh
```

**entrypoint.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

#start SQL Server, start the script to create the DB and import the data, start the app
/usr/src/app/import-data.sh & /opt/mssql/bin/sqlservr
```

**import-data.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
# wait for the SQL Server to come up https://github.com/twright-msft/mssql-node-docker-demo-app/issues/11
while [ ! -f /var/opt/mssql/log/errorlog ]
do
  sleep 2
done

## tail the error log for the startup dll and then quit
tail -f /var/opt/mssql/log/errorlog | while read LOGLINE
do
   [[ "${LOGLINE}" == *"Using 'xpstar.dll' version"* ]] && pkill -P $$ tail
done

echo "Running SQL Scripts"
# Scan for SQL files and load them in
for file in /sql-data/*.sql; do
    echo $file
    /opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -S localhost -U sa -P $SA_PASSWORD -i $file 
done
```

**/sql-data/setup.sql**

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT name FROM master.dbo.sysdatabases WHERE name = 'Products')
BEGIN
    CREATE DATABASE Products;
END
GO

USE Products;
GO
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The SQLCMD utility unfortunately defaults to `QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF` for backwards compatibility reasons. [Specify the `-I` argument so that `QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON` is used.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlcmd-utility)

```
/opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -S localhost -U sa -P $SA_PASSWORD -i $file -I
```

Comment: Thanks @Dan Guzman, this is exactly the solution I need, i.e. no change to the sql script but just the parameter of sqlcmd.exe

Answer (score 1):

Tools like SQL Server Management Studio and Datagrip have Quoted Identifier turned on by default. You must manually enable it in SQLCMD by modifying your SQL Scripts to `SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON`

You would modify your setup.sql script like this:

**/sql-data/setup.sql**

```
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT name FROM master.dbo.sysdatabases WHERE name = 'Products')
BEGIN
    CREATE DATABASE Products;
END
GO

USE Products;
GO
```